# Where are sqlite3 extensions stored and how to load them in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to access the json1 extension in sqlite3 in python 3.6 in linux.

I see from here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.enable_load_extension

I can run:

```
# Load the fulltext search extension
con.execute("select load_extension('./fts3.so')")

# alternatively you can load the extension using an API call:
# con.load_extension("./fts3.so")
```

So, I assume similar should be possible with:

```
con.execute("select load_extension('./json1.so')")
```

If I can track down where that lives. But I cannot find json1.so in the sqlite3 source.

A couple places I have looked for answers:

## First

[Python - SQLite JSON1 load extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319280/python-sqlite-json1-load-extension)

`gcc -g -fPIC -dynamiclib sqlite-src-3140100/ext/misc/json1.c -o json1`

Looks good, but source of sqlite no longer contains an /ext/ or /ext/misc/ directory, so I can't compile this myself.

I am downloading via:

`curl -O https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz
tar -xvzf sqlite-autoconf-3240000.tar.gz`

## Second

http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-the-sqlite-json1-and-fts5-extensions-with-python/

I tried this approach, and starts off looking good, but the step where the custom sqlite3 gets called into the python wrapper when re-compiled uses a library that does not support python3:

`pysqlite is not supported on Python 3. When using Python 3, use the sqlite3 module from the standard library.`

Comment: I'd contact charles leifer for a fix

Comment: How is this question different from the question you linked?

Comment: Which question?  For the former, there no longer exists /ext or /ext/misc/ in the sqlite source, so it is not clear how to compile myself such that I will have the location of the extension.  For the latter, the pysqlite extension does not work with python3.

Comment: If I do use 
curl -O https://sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-src-3240000.zip
I get 
sqlite-src-3240000/ext/misc/json1.c:26:10: fatal error: sqlite3ext.h: No such file or directory
 #include "sqlite3ext.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
So I think a lot has changed since 2016.

Comment: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/compiling-sqlite-for-use-with-python-applications/

Comment: If you're compiling the amalgamation version, it comes with the JSON1 extension as part of it. You just have to add the appropriate define when compiling. See [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html).